# how do I send data from one app.js file to index.ejs file in Routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs, mongoose-schema

error is that my blogs variable which i am passing as an object that contain data to index page is not defined.
code for indexpage:

Thanks in advance.

```js
//INDEX ROUTE
app.get("/blogs", function (req, res){
    Blog.find({}, function (err, blogs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR!");
        } else {
            res.render("index", {blogs: blogs});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using mongoose,`find` method return promise,so make function `async` and use `await` before using `find`:

```
app.get("/blogs", function async (req, res){
  let blogs = await Blogs.find({});
  res.render("index", {blogs});
});
```

***or***

using `.then` to get data from `find` method:

```
app.get("/blogs", function (req, res){
  Blog.find({}).then(blogs=>{
     res.render("index", {blogs}); //if key and value are the same you can skip passing key
  }).catch(err=>{
     console.log(err)
  });
});
```

Comment: @HrithikJaiswal use `console.log(blogs)` before `res.render("index",{blogs});` and see result,if console shows undefined then send your mongoose Blog schema.